# Homemade zoom shows wrong area

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hey so I am working on a zoom function for a project I am working on at my internship. Normally I would just use the zoom provided already in plots and whatnot with matplotlib, but there is a special way we want to analyze multiple images at once that zoom doesn't support. I was trying to write a kind of zoom function that would take an array and slice up only the pieces that I want to show with `imshow()`. Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button, Slider 
import numpy as np

arr = np.zeros([100,100])
for i in range(0,99):
    for j in range(0,99):
        if i % 2 == 0 and j % 2 == 0:
            arr[i][j] = 10
        if i % 3 == 0 and j % 3 == 0:
            arr[i][j] = -7
plt.figure(1)
axpic = plt.subplot2grid((1,1),(0,0), rowspan = 1, colspan = 1)

plt.figure(2)
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((5,5),(0,0), rowspan = 1, colspan = 4)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((5,5),(1,0), rowspan = 1, colspan = 4)
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((5,5),(2,0), rowspan = 1, colspan = 4)
ax4 = plt.subplot2grid((5,5),(3,0), rowspan = 1, colspan = 4)

axbutton = plt.subplot2grid((5,5),(4,4), rowspan = 1, colspan = 1)

s1 = Slider(ax1, 'Row Begin', 0, 99, valinit=0)
s2 = Slider(ax2, 'Row End', 0, 99, valinit=99)
s3 = Slider(ax3, 'Col Begin', 0, 99, valinit=0)
s4 = Slider(ax4, 'Col End', 0, 99, valinit=99)

zoom = Button(axbutton, 'Zoom')

def dat_view_doe(event):
    if event == 'Nothing':
        axpic.imshow(arr, cmap = 'RdBu')
    else:
        plt.figure(1)
        axpic.cla()
        axpic.imshow(arr[int(s1.val):int(s2.val)][int(s3.val):int(s4.val)], cmap = 'RdBu')
        plt.ylim(0, s2.val-s1.val)
        plt.xlim(0, s4.val-s3.val)

zoom.on_clicked(dat_view_doe)

dat_view_doe('Nothing')
plt.show()
```

The zoom is cutting out too many rows, and not cutting out any of the columns of the image array. I am not sure if there is something syntax wise that I am doing wrong, or if there is some deeper issue. Thank you for any and all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least one possible issue with your code is you are both slicing the `arr` when calling imshow as well as changing the axis limits (and setting these from zero to max-min). I would suggest simply adjusting the axis each time, with the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button, Slider 
import numpy as np

arr = np.zeros([100,100])
for i in range(0,99):
    for j in range(0,99):
        if i % 2 == 0 and j % 2 == 0:
            arr[i][j] = 10
        if i % 3 == 0 and j % 3 == 0:
            arr[i][j] = -7
plt.figure(1)
axpic = plt.subplot2grid((1,1),(0,0), rowspan = 1, colspan = 1)

plt.figure(2)
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((5,5),(0,0), rowspan = 1, colspan = 4)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((5,5),(1,0), rowspan = 1, colspan = 4)
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((5,5),(2,0), rowspan = 1, colspan = 4)
ax4 = plt.subplot2grid((5,5),(3,0), rowspan = 1, colspan = 4)

axbutton = plt.subplot2grid((5,5),(4,4), rowspan = 1, colspan = 1)

s1 = Slider(ax1, 'Row Begin', 0, 99, valinit=0)
s2 = Slider(ax2, 'Row End', 0, 99, valinit=99)
s3 = Slider(ax3, 'Col Begin', 0, 99, valinit=0)
s4 = Slider(ax4, 'Col End', 0, 99, valinit=99)

zoom = Button(axbutton, 'Zoom')

def dat_view_doe(event):
    if event == 'Nothing':
        axpic.imshow(arr, cmap = 'RdBu')
    else:
        plt.figure(1)
        plt.xlim(s1.val, s2.val)
        plt.ylim(s3.val, s4.val)
        plt.draw()

zoom.on_clicked(dat_view_doe)

dat_view_doe('Nothing')
plt.show()
```

Comment: This...... works much better and makes more sense. Thank you mr. troll face sir that does exactly what I want. Have a great day.